# Construction of a resolution for a coherent sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a coherent sheaf over a complex manifold $M$. How do I construct a resolution of $\mathcal{S}$ by holomorphic vector bundles? Is this construction "unique"? Are the answers the same when $\mathcal{S}$ is a vector bundle over a subvariety?

I would be interested in references on the differential geometry side if there exists some (else any would be appreiated).

Thanks in advance

Comment: as a side note, although (as the accepted answer says) coherent analytic sheaves "rarely" admit resolutions by locally free sheaves, if you're happy to pass to simplicial objects, then you *can* resolve every coherent analytic sheaf by locally free sheaves *on the Čech nerve*. This is a result from a PhD thesis by Green in 1980, which I expanded upon a bit in my PhD thesis :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would want to do is to find a surjective morphism from a locally free sheaf $\mathcal{L}_0$ to $\mathcal{S}$, then find a surjective morphism from a locally free sheaf $\mathcal{L}_1$ to the kernel of $\mathcal{L}_0\to \mathcal{S}$, and repeat: this would give you a locally free resolution.

In general, you can't do this because of the following counterexample of Voisin:

> On any generic complex torus of dimension at least 4, the ideal sheaf of a point does not admit a global locally free resolution.

(This is from her article "A Counterexample to the Hodge Conjecture Extended to Kahler Varieties", available [here](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~claire.voisin/Articlesweb/hodgeimrn.pdf)).

Even if you could do this in general, it is not true that such a resolution would be unique: just direct sum in a copy of the complex $0\to \mathcal{O}_X\stackrel{id}{\to}\mathcal{O}_X\to 0$ somehwere. What you would want to say is that these resolutions are unique up to chain homotopy or something like that, coming from the "fact" that a locally free sheaf is a projective object. But this "fact" is false, as seen in Piotr Achinger's example found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/109432):

> This is never true whenever $X$ has positive dimension. Let $L$ be ample on $X$ and let $E$ be a nonzero coherent sheaf on $X$. Let $P$ be any point of $X$ at which $E$ has a nonzero fiber, so we get a surjection $\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_P$ ($\mathcal{O}_P$ being the skyscraper sheaf at $P$). We can also find a $k>0$ such that the sheaf $\mathrm{Hom}(E, E\otimes L^{-k})= \mathrm{End}(E)\otimes L^{-k}$ has no nonzero global sections. Now tensor the surjection $\mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{O}_P$ by $E$ and $E\otimes L^{-k}$, getting surjections $a:E\to E_P$ and $b:E\otimes L^{-k}\to (E\otimes L^{-k})_P = E_P$. We cannot lift $a$ along $b$ because by assumption on $k$ there are no nonzero maps $E\to E\otimes L^{-k}$.

Nothing changes if you move to considering coherent sheaves which are supported on a proper submanifold.

Comment: Using Oka's Theorem (i.e. $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a coherent sheaf when $X$ is a complex manifold) one can prove that Ker$(\mathcal{O}U^{\oplus q}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_U^{\oplus p})$ is coherent, where $U\subset X$ is open. Using this one can construct a finite locally-free resolution for the initial coherent sheaf (by using the definition of coherence and shrinking the subset $U$ when necessary). Shouldn't this induce a finite resolution of holomorphic bundles?

Comment: @John117 No, this example is rather famous and I'm afraid you're stuck with its truth. Unfortunately this area isn't really something I'm focusing on right now and I think you'd stand a better/quicker chance of getting a good answer by asking a new question rather than waiting for me to get around to it.

Comment: No, of course I believe in the example. I was trying to figure out what the mistake was in my reasoning but I think I got there.

Comment: @John117 the thing that goes wrong with your argument is that the resolution that you construct is defined only on an open subset, which possibly shrinks at each stage of the construction, meaning you only end up with *local* resolutions (see the bottom of p. 696 of Principles of Algebraic Geometry for this exact argument)